# How to properly frame a collate command in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, collate

I'm trying to write a query across two linked servers. Having set up the link with an appropriate logon, I'm getting this collate error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict
>   between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
>   and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the
>   equal to operation.

This is new to me, but it looks like a charset conflict, so I googled it and discovered the collate command which can be added to my join. However I've tried both

```
va ON V_ID1 = c1.strData COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

and

```
va ON V_ID1 = c1.strData COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And neither seems to resolve the error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The entire query is too big to post and expect people to filter through, but here's the relevant bit:

```
   select
        rel.intParentAttributeId as intItemId,
        case va.type
        when 'SM' then 120000000
        when 'FB' then 110000000
        when 'RO' then 100000000
        when 'SP' then 90000000
        when 'A' then 80000000
        when 'D' then 70000000
        when 'P' then 60000000
        when 'SR' then 50000000
        when 'FN' then 40000000
        when 'RL' then 30000000
        when 'VO' then 20000000
        when 'RE' then 10000000
        end
        +

        rel.intParentAttributeId
        as fltStrength
        from
        AttributeMap ky

        join Catalogue c1 on c1.intRowId=ky.intChildAttributeId and c1.intAttributeTypeId=@intsimilarAtt

        join

        [SQLSERVERNAME].[SchemaName].dbo.VidAssc
         va on V_ID1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = c1.strData COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS


        join Catalogue c2 on c2.strData=V_ID2 and c2.intAttributeTypeId=@intsimilarAtt

        join AttributeMap rel on rel.intChildAttributeId = c2.intRowId

        join @tmpSeeds s on s.intItemId = ky.intParentAttributeId

        group by rel.intParentAttributeId,va.Type

        )sqi
```

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Could you please post the entire query?  There might be something in there that you're taking for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally found a fix. Here's what you have to do:

In sql server manager to to Server Objects > Linked Servers > and find the problematic linked server.

Right Click > Properties

Under Server Options set "Use Remote Collation" to "False" 
and "Collation Name" to "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `COLLATE` on the left side as well:

```
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
 ON t1.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
  = t2.ID --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS --optionally on the right if needed.
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help. Trying this nets the error: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.